# What's wrong with my TensorFlow run cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py

Tags: python, tensorflow

My system is :

```
Linux dl1 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Mar 6 11:36:42 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and my GPU :

[image]

It is ok to run sample models like `mnist` and `cifar10` single GPU version.
so I think my installation of tf is no problem.

BUT, when I run :

```
python python cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py --num_gpus=4
```

I got this error :

> ValueError: Variable conv1/weights/ExponentialMovingAverage/ does not
>   exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set
>   reuse=None in VarScope?

Comment: add some code, but the error seems to be that you set the parameter reuse when creating the variable. It could also be that the cifar example was done for an old version of tensorflow and now it is failing due a changes in the api. Try with tensorflow 0.10

Answer (score 0):

Is there any code to see?
I personally think this problem is caused because you didn't reuse **sharing variables** for different inputs in different gpus, check out whether this line `tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()` is in your loop for each gpu

Comment: version of your tf?

Comment: tf version is 0.12.head

Comment: # Reuse variables for the next tower.
tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()

Comment: i find what you mentioned code, how can i fix this problem